# Token concatenation using ## for Array value error

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am just using the "Token concatenation with ## " for getting each array.
Some reference i have taken from https://www.ibm.com/docs/ja/rdfi/9.6.0?topic=definitions-multiple-function-declarations-only

Below is the snippet from my code

**macro:**

```
#define Columnsize(x) x##[0]
#define get_arrsize(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(Columnsize(x))
```

**Code:**

```
uint8 test_array[4][7]= {"ok","me","hello","hi"};
get_arrsize(test_array)
```

After compilations, I am getting below error

```
error: pasting ")" and "[" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    | #define Columnsize(x) (x)##[0]
```

Any suggestion how to solve this error? Why this is failed?

Comment: I don't spot the problem either but every compiler provides the option to preserve the preprocessor output, (e.g. with `gcc -E`. IIRC).

Comment: You can't paste those together, and there is no reason to try. Just write `x[0]`

Comment: The compiler says you defined `Columnsize` as `(x)##[0]`. You say you defined it as `x##[0]`. Which is it?

Comment: What problem is the `Columnsize` macro supposed to solve to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way tokenization works. The gcc documentation has [a page about tokenization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html) and [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) from which I glean the following:

The preprocessor separates the source code into tokens which are roughly equivalent to the C compiler tokens (e.g. literals, identifiers or operators). These tokens can be combined with the `##` operator. **The result of the concatenation must in turn be a token** (for example, an identifier-shaped thing, a number, an operator), which is not the case here, which is why the compiler complains.

The key is that the character sequence `[0]` *is separated into the three-token sequence* `[`, `0`, `]`. The concatenation operator uses only `[` as its right hand side operator; the result `x[` is not a token.

As a counter-example, the following works:

```c
#define MAKE_ASSIGN_OP(x) x##=
int main() { int x=1; return x MAKE_ASSIGN_OP(+) 1; }
```

Both `+` and `=` as well as their concatenation `+=`  are valid tokens.

As an example

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestion how to solve this error

Remove `##`

> Why this is failed?

Because `x[` is not a (single) valid token.